# VBA - FOR EACH cell .Formula

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I have been searching so long have problem with error 1004
Need to do this way: How to put `.formula` to next column for each cell

```
Sub test() 

    Dim adres_img, link, img, urlfile, cv, hyp, ob, f1, f2, f3, cu As String

    Dim cell, img_put, col_model, dane As Range 

    Dim foto As Shape, ws As Worksheet, x, i, iend, xend As Integer

    Dim ImageCell As Range 
    cu = Chr(34)

    For x = 1 To xend 
      ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(x).Select
      Set ws = ActiveSheet 
      For Each cell In dane

          If Not cell = "" And Not cell = "z" And Not cell = "0"  Then
                 
             cv = Left(cell.Value, 11)  ' this is picture                 
             link = "https://www.domain.zz/EU/" & cv & "-HERO?wid=800&hei=800"   '
             img = "https://www.domain.zz/EU/" & cv & "-HERO?wid=100&hei=100"                 
             ob = "PICTURE(" & Chr(34) & img & Chr(34) & ";0;0)"                 
             hyp = "=HIPERŁĄCZE(" & Chr(34) & link & Chr(34) & ";" & ob & ")"                 
             ws.Cells(cell.Row, "B").Value = "PICTURE(" & Chr(34) & img & Chr(34) & ";0;0)" 'work                 
             ws.Cells(cell.Row, "B").Fomula = "=PICTURE(" & Chr(34) & img & Chr(34) & ";0;0)"  'this is problem                                                                 
         End If             
         On Error GoTo 0                      
       Next  
    Next x

End Sub
```

I am trying change Macro. Using VBA for many sheets. There is A column with indexes which I use to link. Old Macro was putting shape as pictures. In office 365 there is new Function `PICTURE(url_of_image;size)` and it is much lighter and faster. I need to put this function for each row where is indexes.

Comment: You have `Fomula` not `Formula`

Comment: `Formula` requires `,` as the separator, not `;`.

Comment: *In office 365 there is new Function* Did you mean [IMAGE()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/image-function-7e112975-5e52-4f2a-b9da-1d913d51f5d5)